# What MapReduce Framework is?

Tags: hadoop, architecture, mapreduce, frameworks

I have a project to do and I have to explain how does MapReduce works.

The name itself is "MapReduce framework", so here is the problem. What does this mean?? Could someone give me an example and explain to me where do I have to imagine this framework takes places (internet, cloud, work nodes...)?

Thank you very much.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MapReduce is a framework developed at Google to abstract away from the complexity of distributed computations.  It allows you to easily parallelize computations over a large distributed network of nodes. It can be used for web indexing, ranking, machine learning, graph computations, data analysis, large database join among many other things.

Edmond Lau explains the concept in the name "a *Map* function to transform inputs from one form to another, and a *Reduce* function to combine intermediate data and produce output. Hadoop MapReduce is a popular open source framework inspired by Googles.

An example would be using MapReduce to compute the frequency of every single word across the billions of web pages in its search index.